# Creating a join list between two tables VBA

Tags: vba, join, match, analysis

Good afternoon,

I am still quite a novice with VBA but am trying to create a loop that will be able to sift through a long list of data within a given column (in my case, both tables have one common identifier, the system ID) and if a system ID is matched in one column with a column from the other table, then a new sheet is created that combines all of the rows associated with both sets of data into one row.

For example, if my data looked like this:

Table 1
Column A, Column B, Column C    |
   ID,      Name,     Birthday

Table 2

Column A, Column B, Column C|

Purchase,  Amount,    ID

And I had the same ID in both Tables 1 and 2, for each match, I would like to have all rows associated with the match joined together.

This would really enable me to speed things up with organizing information, so I was not sure if it would be possible...  Any Ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

since excel is not a database program like access, you can not use sql-like joins natively. you would have to program your own join function:
(Since i do not have MS Office installed, i can only give you pseudo-code)

```
for each-loop going through IDs of Table1

for each-loop going through IDs of Table2

  if(Table1.ID = Table2.ID) then
   copy data of Table1 into a new sheet
   copy data of Table2 into the same sheet, next to Table1 data
```

PS: i assume you use excel because of the vocabulary (column, worksheet,..)